# alert for new update in php or javascript

Tags: php

How to change background color for  last render row in while loop ....

that is

```
row1
row2
**row3**
```

If row4 is added then it should

```
row1
row2
row3
**row4**
```

that is star represents some bgcolor red...

this loop am following,,,,
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

```
$out_data[] = "<p>$i {$row['news']} </p>";

$i++;
}

$divider = '<div class="border"></div>';
$output = implode ($divider, $out_data);

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can  use mysql_num_rows to get the number of rows you have before the while loop.

```
 $row_count = mysql_num_rows($sql)
```

inside the while loop

```
 if ($i==$row_count)
    // put color $out_data[] = "<p style="colorsomething">$i {$row['news']} </p>";
 else
    // dont put color $out_data[] = "<p>$i {$row['news']} </p>";
```

does this help?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You'd need to change the formatting for the last element of `$out_data` like this:
(once the while loop completes)

```
…
$out_data[ count($out_data) - 1 ] = "<div style='background-color:red'>" . end($out_data) . "</div>"

$divider = '<div class="border"></div>';
$output = implode ($divider, $out_data);

echo $output;
```

how does that work?

Comment: assume....to put an alternate row color we know...we use somthing like this formulat...and make alternate row colors
   $tr_color = $i%2;

Comment: The background-color property can be in the rgb(0-255, 0-255, 0-255) format or in hex color codes.

Comment: what should i put instead of  last time condition is true

Comment: what is the test case i should put there.

Comment: Could I see your while loop condition?

Comment: am not understand about the above while loop..bcoz in while i should use the (LOOP)  while($row=mysql_fetch_array) .....how i proceed for my question...